# Login SSO type of G suite in angular2

Tags: angular, google-signin, google-workspace

I'm starting with angluar2 and I would like to make a GSS input type of G suite to achieve it (but I can not figure out how). Guide me? I do not know if a login is done with normal google?

Comment: If you are posting here, please post in English. Otherwise, there is an es.stackoverflow.com that you can post in Spanish.

Comment: @Mónica Si está publicando aquí, publique en inglés. De lo contrario, hay un `es.stackoverflow.com` donde puede publicar sus preguntas en español.